# node js sha256 generated string does not match

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sha256

I am trying to validate signature with HMAC  for an API service

Their documentation

The signature in the X-Line-Signature request header must be verified to confirm that the request was sent from the LINE Platform.

Authentication is performed as follows:

```
The signature in the X-Line-Signature request header must be verified to confirm that the request was sent from the LINE Platform.

Authentication is performed as follows:

1)With the channel secret as the secret key, your application retrieves the digest value in the request body created using the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm.

2)The server confirms that the signature in the request header matches the digest value which is Base64 encoded.
```

Here is the implementation with nodejs

```
 const crypto    = require('crypto');
    const signature = crypto.createHmac('SHA256', doc.line.channelSecret).update(JSON.stringify(req.body)).digest('base64');
```

But the generated signature and the signature from the header is does not match

**UPDATED**

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

const channelSecret = ...; // Channel secret string
const body = ...; // Request body string
const signature =
  createHmac('SHA256', channelSecret)
  .update(body).digest('base64');
// Compare X-Line-Signature request header and the signature
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `createHmac` instead of `createHash`? And are you sure that `JSON.stringify(req.body)` creates the expected output?

Comment: Updated with `createHmac` but still the same Jreq.body gives the proper result

Comment: From my experience I know that often API services require the body parameters to be sorted and transformed in a certain way before you verify the signature. Did you double check if something like this is needed?

Comment: @QiongWu its needed one

Comment: from what I found out at https://github.com/line/line-bot-sdk-nodejs/blob/15c64ff09df383982d83e9c355f72b44c26457b5/lib/validate-signature.ts#L34 and https://qiita.com/yorifuji/items/71e31baf896adb69f567 your approach seems to be correct. maybe theres an issue with the secret?

Comment: @t.niese i think its the problem with key  when i try with `doc.line.channelSecret` and doc.line.channelSecret.toString() both returns different result

Comment: is channelSecret not stored as a string in your app? if its only made up of numbers, there might be an issue with that

Comment: Looks like channel secret is hex value

Comment: @iambatman Are you completely sure that the json is correct? In the sense that whitespaces match? And the order of keys? Note that hash functions require **exact** same string. Two jsons can be equal even though they are not equal as serialized strings, e.g. `{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}` and `{"bar": 2, "foo":1}` are the same json even though will give different hashes.

Comment: Yea its correct and its coming from their API

Comment: @iambatman What is coming from API? You are doing `JSON.stringify` so the resulting hash **depends** on your `JSON` implementation. Hence this is definitely wrong. If it works, then only by chance. But please check that the result of `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Here is the result of JSON.stringify `{"events":[{"replyToken":"00000000000000000000000000000000","type":"message","timestamp":1517819381376,"source":{"type":"user","userId":"Udeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"},"message":{"id":"100001","type":"text","text":"Hello, world"}},{"replyToken":"ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff","type":"message","timestamp":1517819381376,"source":{"type":"user","userId":"Udeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef"},"message":{"id":"100002","type":"sticker","packageId":"1","stickerId":"1"}}]}`

Comment: @iambatman Ok, so what is the expected JSON? Note that I can change the order of keys and I will still get the same json, but different hash.

Comment: Check my updated question it contains the sample code from their API doc

Comment: Further more from their doc  `With the channel secret as the secret key, your application retrieves the digest value in the request body created using the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164531/discussion-between-iam-batman-and-freakish).